# Matrix multiplication using Matrix Template library (MTL 4)

Tags: c++, boost, vector, linear-algebra

The program is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp>
using namespace mtl;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
dense_vector<double> a(5,1.0);
dense_vector<double> b(5,2.0);
a * trans(b);
}
```

I want to calculate a * trans(b), but there is a compling error :C2893.
Will someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would help if you provide the complete error text from the output window.  C2893 doesn't say a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

The vector in your program above is a column vector. The constructor you make use of takes two arguments: the size and the initial value.

The reason you're getting the compiler error is probably this:

> The transposition of vector is
>   momentarily not implemented yet. It
>   will create a row vector view on a
>   column vector and vice versa.

[Matrix Template Library 4: Transposed](http://osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/mtl4/doc/trans__intro.html)